# Dataset is empty while it is not empty at first

Tags: vb.net

I have the following piece of code

```
_Foo = String.Concat(_Foo, " Var = '", _varValue, "' ")
_Bar = DsInvoice.viewInvoice.Select(_Foo, _Order)
If _Bar.Count > 0 Then
```

When I place the debug lines, the Dataset is actually returning rows, and _Bar has a count of 116. Yet when it is at the 3rd line (the if statement)  _Bar is empty and the count returns 0. Without any reason I just lost my data.

Let me know if you need more information (I'm actually a PHP programmer and I had to fix a legacy bit of code :(. I lack VB experience to give more background information on this code.

Comment: `_Bar = DsInvoice.viewInvoice.Select("Property = " & value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Bar` has no rows because there is no value equal to the _varValue in the "Column" (a.k.a "Property") in the datatable.

*Even if the Property is numeric I doubt wrapping it with single quotes will matter. *

Tip: F8 (VB.Net) or F11 (C#) to step the code control (Yellow Line) onto the second line of code. Then hover your mouse over the `viewInvoice` word on the second line shown in your question, you'll see the ObjectBrowser Tooltip appear and in it will be a Magnifying Glass with a dropdown. Click it (the dropdown) and select the DataTable View to help you debug this problem.

You can change the `Select(...)` criteria in run/debug time and then (by dragging the yellow arrow in the line number margin up a line) see the effect of the different `Select` criteria to work out what is going wrong.

Comment: Does this make sense, you check the DataSets' Datatable "viewInvoice" on the second line in your question, by using this Object Browser Tooltip Datatable to see if it has a `Var` column with the value `_varValue`..  if the Object Browser Tooltip Datatable doesn't have the _varValue in the Var column then the problem is with populating the DataSets Datatable. If the `var` column does have the _varValue present - then triple check your syntax is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that the select on the dataset was actually some sort of query on the DB itself. I rechecked the dataset and figured out the the set was filled with other conditions in which the statement from line 2 did not yield any results.  It was actually pretty simple but I never worked with these datasets before.